# CI Builds not starting anymore

Tags: build, credentials

I got the following error while checking in changes on our CI build :

```
TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition \[builddefinitionofourcompany].: 
Exception Message: Derived method 'get_CredentialType' in type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client.VssFederatedCredential' from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' cannot reduce access. (type TypeLoadException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsClientCredentialsConverter.ConvertToVssCredentials(TfsClientCredentials clientCredentials, Uri serverUri)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.CreateVssConnection()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.GetClientT
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.FileContainerHelper.GetFile(TfsTeamProjectCollection projectCollection, String itemPath, Stream outputStream)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.FileContainerHelper.GetFileAsString(TfsTeamProjectCollection projectCollection, String itemPath)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.ProcessTemplate.Download(String sourceGetVersion)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildControllerWorkflowManager.PrepareRequestForBuild(WorkflowManagerActivity activity, IBuildDetail build, WorkflowRequest request, IDictionary`2 dataContext)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildWorkflowManager.TryStartWorkflow(WorkflowRequest request, WorkflowManagerActivity activity, BuildWorkflowInstance& workflowInstance, Exception& error, Boolean& syncLockTaken)
```

What is this credential error? Google isn't giving any results.

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 0):

I just have this problem. I go to TFS Build server, open Team Foundation Server Management Console, "Restart" the topmost BUILDER, then it solved.